# How to Cast recovered JSON object when testing Controller in MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to write some automated end to end integration tests for my MVC Controllers as we have strict testing requirements,  it is not sufficient for me to just test the services.

I have a controller with the method:

```
 [HttpGet("myPath")]
 public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Foo>>> GetFoos()
 {
    Return Ok( _service.GetFoos()); 
 }
```

I would like to test it as follows:

```
Public Async Task TestController(){
…
Var result=await Client.GetAsync("/myPath");  var jsonFromResponse = await 
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var myList=(IEnumerable<Foo>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonFromResponse);

// PERFORM ASSERTION on myList
}
```

However this is givine the exception

> ---> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Foo]'.

My returned JSON resultseems OK, it is:

```
[
  {
    "type": 1,
    "study": {
      "id": 96,
      "createdDate": "2017-10-10T00:00:00",
      "updatedDate": null,
      "X": null
    },
    "id": 262,
    "createdDate": "2019-10-14T07:36:40.104368",
    "updatedDate": "2019-10-14T07:36:40.118568"
  },
  {
    "type": 1,
    "study": {
      "id": 96,
      "createdDate": "2017-10-10T00:00:00",
      "updatedDate": null,
      "X": null
    },
    "id": 263,
    "createdDate": "2019-10-14T07:36:40.147418",
    "updatedDate": "2019-10-14T07:36:40.160704"
  },

…
]
```

Comment: you should use the `DeserializeObject<T>` with required type as `var myList=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Foo>>(jsonFromResponse);` This will automatically gives the response in `IEnumerable<Foo>`.

Comment: just tested , your suggestion works, strange that deserializeobject followed by the case does not work,  but your solution is cleaner in any case!

Comment: The `DeserializeObject` returns `JArray` that's why you are getting the cast exception. With overloaded method, the library converts the JArray to required specified type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the implementation of deserializing the object to `DeserializeObject<T>`

```
var myList=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Foo>>(jsonFromResponse);
```

The above code will automatically return the object in required `T`.

Read the details about DeserializeObject at [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm)